# how to shift backward in time a date column and keep the same date in the last row of each group?

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by

i'm scratching my head on this problem for a while now. I have a log with a case id, an activity id and the date in which the activity occurred. i need to add a column which will represent the end timestamp (DATEEND), but i don't know how to make the last date in the column DATEEND of each case id as the last date in the column DATESTART.

i was thinking about using groupby() and shift(-1), but then i don't know how to fix the last date. Any idea?

Input:

```
CASEID   ACTIVITYID DATESTART
725/2022 _0         2022-03-09
725/2022 0F         2022-03-23
725/2022 YB         2022-06-21
725/2022 AA         2022-06-28
725/2022 1F         2022-06-28
725/2022 2B         2022-06-29
444/2022 AA         2022-07-26
444/2022 1F         2022-07-28
444/2022 2B         2022-07-28
```

Output:

```
CASEID   ACTIVITYID DATESTART  DATEEND    
725/2022 _0         2022-03-09 2022-03-23 
725/2022 0F         2022-03-23 2022-06-21 
725/2022 YB         2022-06-21 2022-06-28 
725/2022 AA         2022-06-28 2022-06-28 
725/2022 1F         2022-06-28 2022-06-29 
725/2022 2B         2022-06-29 2022-06-29 
444/2022 AA         2022-07-26 2022-07-28 
444/2022 1F         2022-07-28 2022-07-28 
444/2022 2B         2022-07-28 2022-07-28
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by column `DATESTART`:

```
df['DATEEND'] = df.groupby('CASEID')['DATESTART'].shift(-1).fillna(df['DATESTART'])
print (df)
     CASEID ACTIVITYID   DATESTART     DATEEND
0  725/2022         _0  2022-03-09  2022-03-23
1  725/2022         0F  2022-03-23  2022-06-21
2  725/2022         YB  2022-06-21  2022-06-28
3  725/2022         AA  2022-06-28  2022-06-28
4  725/2022         1F  2022-06-28  2022-06-29
5  725/2022         2B  2022-06-29  2022-06-29
6  444/2022         AA  2022-07-26  2022-07-28
7  444/2022         1F  2022-07-28  2022-07-28
8  444/2022         2B  2022-07-28  2022-07-28
```